# How to use verb with word "some" and "most" in a sentence?

Tags: verbs

Some of the sweets (appear/appears) to be spoilt, while most of the pudding (seem/seems) edible.

which one looks like apt verb for the sentence?

Answer (score 1):

*Some* means "more than one but not all" if the noun is countable.  So you use it as a determiner to a plural noun and with plural verb forms.

> Some sweets are spolit.

You can use *some* with a non-countable noun to mean "not all of it".  In this case, singular is used.

> Some water is polluted.

Comment: how about this particular sentence I added? (appear/appears) and (seem/seems) ? Because it has "Some of the entity". Not just "Some entity".

Comment: Same as without "of". Some of the sweets appear to be spoilt. Most of the pudding appears to be edible. Most of the water appears to be polluted.